# Update mysql table with radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

I'm rather new to PHP and MySQL, and even programming at all. 
I'm trying to update a value in a table using radio button. That value would later be read over Arduino, but that irrelavant now.
I set up a database and created a table named "elementi". It contains only one column named "stanje" of type "tinyint(1)" to use it as boolean.

Now here's my code, so could anyone tell me why it doesn't work, and what should I change?
Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

 $(document).ready(function() { 
       $('input[name=stanje]').change(function(){
        $('form').submit();
   });
  });

</script>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="stanje" value="1">Upali<br>
<input type="radio" name="stanje" value="0">Ugasi<br>
<input type="submit" value="Odaberi">
</form>

</body>
</html> 

<?php

if (!$spoj=@mySQL_connect("hostname", "username", "password")) {
    die ('Greska u korisnickim podacima!'); }

if (!mySQL_select_db("b24_14990027_peho", $spoj)) {
    die ('Greska u odabiru baze!');}

$sql_upit="UPDATE 'elementi' SET 'stanje'='".$POST["stanje"]."'";

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to programming! We're glad to have you. This forum really isn't for really general questions - I'd suggest first finding examples of the [`mysqli_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) family of `PHP` functions (specifically, [`mysqli_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)) and come back when you have a specific question :)

Comment: remove single quotes for column names in your query

Comment: FerozAkbar, nope, that didn't help 
@jterry thanks! I've tried with mysqli_query and still it doesn't work. The code:
`<?php
$spoj=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","db_name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_query($spoj,"UPDATE elementi SET stanje='".$_POST["stanje"]."'");
mysqli_close($spoj);

?>`